# How to increase the hard disk space of thin provisioning virtual machine?

Tags: vmware, esxi, suse

Created thin provisioning VM (Suse Linux) with 100 GB hard disk. Now due to space requirements, I need to increase the size to 200GB. Can someone please tell me how to increase the space of the "/" directory?

```
Below is the output of the df -h command.

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs            12G  8.0K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4.7G   18M  4.7G   1% /run
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        92G   53G   40G  57% /
/dev/sda1       511M  4.9M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           2.4G   56K  2.4G   1% /run/user/467
tmpfs           2.4G   40K  2.4G   1% /run/user/465
tmpfs           2.4G   44K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           2.4G   40K  2.4G   1% /run/user/0
```

```
Below is the output of the fdisk -l command.

GPT PMBR size mismatch (209715199 != 419430399) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sda: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 055ED88C-4E22-4F03-9C7F-4E4CCADBF54C

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  193429504 209715166  16285663  7.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda3    1050624 193429503 192378880 91.7G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I tried Fixing the partition and Correcting the GPT PMBR size mismatch using the below commands and rebooted. The system reboots fine.

```
Enter into the disk partition place: 
fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help):   m  
Command action
  ...
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

Command (m for help):   x

Expert command (m for help):   m
Command action
...
   f   fix partition order
   m   print this menu
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   r   return to main menu
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit

Expert command (m for help):   f
Done.

Expert command (m for help):   w

The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

I turn off SWAP and delete the SWAP partition. I then deleted the "/" partition and created it again with the intended size of 190G.

```
Commands used:

swapoff -a

fdisk  /dev/sda
```

As "/" is still showing the older size I run the command xfs_growfs -d /. The size of the partition increases as intended. Now the issue is my system does not boot in normal mode(Just stays on 4 dots and lizard sign) whereas I can boot into recovery mode.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What hypervisor are you using and did you run the appropriate command to increase the virtual HDD size before you attempted to increase the size within the OS?

Comment: I am using VMware ESXI version 7.0.3. I shut the Virtual Machine and increased the size of the virtual machine's hard disk. Earlier it was showing 100 GB and then I changed 100 GB to 200 GB.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The " / " partition was extended. However, on rebooting after all the activities bootloader was still trying to access the old UUID belonging to the SWAP partition. I updated the UUID and it started booting properly.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions and support.